# WebView on Android 7.0+ doesn't render page

Tags: android, webview, chromium, android-7.0-nougat

I have WebView screen with license. And everything worked perfectly until users notified me that nothing shows on Android 7+ devices.

```
public class DefaultWebActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.default_web);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.w("WebActivity", "Error loading page " + description);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume();
}
```

}

I can see that it loads something(google url appears in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method) but it shows nothing. *No error logs appear.*

*This code perfectly works on <7.0 android version devices.*
I have read that Android 7+ uses Chrome to render screen but I didn't fount what I have to add to fix issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue exactly on Android 7.0+
Logs:

 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.db>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Android doc

This is pre Android N

```
@Deprecated
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
}
```

This is since Android N

> - @return True if the host application wants to leave the current WebView
>
>   - and handle the url itself, otherwise return false.

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return true;
    }
```

This method is from Android N , so for this reason you have this issue only in Android N.
Returning false you should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstand those methods desciption. False is correct value. True means that app handled url

Comment: Hello Sir, I have use Google pixel. i have face same problem and as per your comment i have update my crome app but still same issue face. Please reply me any other solution. thank you in advance.

Comment: Tried `true`, tried `false`...Changes nothing for me.

Comment: @DheerajKumar had this same. After gradle update to 3.4.0 and gms update to 4.2.0 problem seems to be gone.