# android - open external link in webview app

Tags: java, android

When i click an external link from browser/mail, my webview-app opens (this work).

..and now the problem:
If the app is closed, the link will open correctly.
If the app is already open, the link does not open.

I was thinking of fixing with "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" but the function is never called.

---- start code ----

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private WebView mWebView;
private Bundle savedInstanceState;

/**
 * Dichiariamo l'attributo di classe url in cui
 * salviamo l'indirizzo web che aprirà la webview
 */
private String url = "https://asp-center.fgp.biz?app=1&id=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (savedInstanceState != null && intent.getData() != null) {
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //carichiamo la webview dentro il layout specificato
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        //permette di gestire i _blank
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
            String data = result.getExtra();
            Log.d("DATA", "" + data);
            // view.loadUrl(data);

            WebView newWebView = new WebView(view.getContext());
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(view);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            return true;
        }

    });

    mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


    // prendo l'id del dispositivo che mi aiuta a controllare se è attivo l'auto-accesso (non sono richieste credenziali) per il suddetto dispositivo
    String android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    //scrivo del testo di debug
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText("start");


    //imposto la url di default per l'apertura della app
    String url = "http://fgp.intranet/ggweb/gol_home_mobile.php?app=1&id_device=" + android_id;

    //controllo se l'apertura della app è stata fatta da un link esterno (come le mail di notifica richieste)
    if(intent.getData() != null) {

        //se è stata aperta esternamente, apro il link passato
        url = intent.getData().toString();
        t.setText(url);
        //url2 = intent.getData().toString();

    } else {



    }

    //carichiamo la url nella webview
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setText("shouldOverrideUrlLoading!");

        System.out.println("here");
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("fgp.intranet")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText("bbbbbbbb!");

    String url=request.getUrl().toString();
    view.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    return true;
}
*/

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: some month ago i was answer the similarly question. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367358/webview-on-android-7-0-doesnt-render-page/42367622#42367622

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebView on Android 7.0+ doesn't render page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367358/webview-on-android-7-0-doesnt-render-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nee to handle the in onNewIntent. On create never called again if activity is already open.

```
@Override
 protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent == null) {
        return;
    }else{
       // Your code to handle intent 
    }
}
```

Comment: I love you bro <3

WORK PERFECTLY